# Capital accented e with Caps Lock + key

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, capslock, dead-keys

I'm Italian, so sometimes I have to start a sentence with the letter 'è' (it is the third singular person of the present simple of the verb 'to be').

In Linux, writing that capital character is easily achieved by hitting the key next to the 'p' one (in the Italian layout, it prints 'è') with the `Caps Lock` key on. How can I achieve such a thing in Windows? It would be much better than having to remember the ASCII code every time, also considering that I'm on a laptop, so I should use the `Fn` jey to enable the numeric keypad, but the combination `Alt`+`Fn`+`7` and such is already assigned to some default functions. I should enable `Num LK` every time and disable it afterwards.

I'm aware of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/844000/windows-7-italian-keyboard-typing-capitalized-accented-vowels), but I'd prefer to have it with `Caps Lock` + `è` if possible, because the è key is occupied in all of its combinations (with `Shift` it prints 'é', with `Alt Gr` '[' and with `Shift`+`Alt Gr` '{'), and using `Alt Gr` with other keys would arise confusion and occupy a combination which I could use for other characters (like greek letters I use for physics or other ASCII symbols), like it is in Linux for the Eliminate Dead Keys kayout

Comment: The answer is the same: MSKLC (Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator). With this tool you can define **any** combination you like to do, even with dead-keys or `Caps Look` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer, use MSKLC (Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator).

As an example you here the mapping for key `E`:

- normal: e
- Shift: E
- Ctrl+Alt: €
- Caps Lock: è
- Caps Lock + Shift: È

[image]